# How to Count number of lines of javascript in php files?

Tags: php, javascript, command-line, count

I need to count the no. of lines of inline java script between script tags in php files. How do I do it? Will grep linux command suffice or I can get some tool to do it? Please help.

Comment: how do you propose to count `<script type="text/javascript">alert('hello');</script>` vs. `<script type="text/javascript">\nalert('hello');\n</script>`

Comment: If I can do it from command line with grep, wc and awk it would be great. I need a report like 

index.php 40
about.php 50

40 and 50 are lines of inline javascript.

Answer (score 3):

You might use a regular expression like to extract the content of each SCRIPT tag in your files and than count the \n occurrences within the content.

This regex should match all script tag including the opening and closing tag:

```
 /<script[^>]*?>(.*)?</script>/sm
```

You should than remove the tags and lines without any code to count the real lines of JavaScript code.

Comment: What about `alert('</script>');` ?

Comment: Why would such a line of code make any sense? Why not giving me a good example on how my code fails like echo '</'.'script'.'>'; :) You can every find a string that would destory the matching now matter how good it is. But I think a basic idea should be enough.

Comment: How do I use it with grep can you give an example.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not a linux user and I don't really know how to do that with grep. But I don't think you can do it with a single grep command, as you will have to count the line breaks of the regex match.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look on the following code,it works but you may need to updates as per your requirements

```
<?php
$file = file('thisfile.php');
for($i=0;$i<count($file);$i++)
{
    if(trim($file[$i]) == "<script language=\"javascript\">")
    {
        $start = $i.'<br>';
    }
    if(trim($file[$i]) == "</script>")
    {
        $end = $i.'<br>';
    }

}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script language="javascript">
var a = 10;
var b = 10;
var c = 10;
var d = 10;
var e = 10;
var e = 10;
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo ($end - $start)-1; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

save this php file as thisfile.php then try

Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this from a processed HTML page, use [`DOM`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to get all script tags without a `src` attribute. Then for each found node split the child TextNode by the linebreak or simple count them. Done.

If you need to grab this from actual PHP source code, use the [`Tokenizer`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php) to find [`T_STRINGS` and similar parser tokens](https://www.php.net/manual/en/tokens.php) and analyze them for `<script>` blocks, but note that it might be impossible to find them all, if there is code like:

```
 echo '<' . $scriptTag . '>' . $code . '</' . $scriptTag . '>';
```

because that wont be analyzable as a JavaScript String before PHP processed it.